# Remove the UIView at Runtime and Automatically Correct the UI

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController. I have made a MyProfile section. Now what i want to do is that if a person has only one picture then the 4 images section (which is a uiview) disappear and my UI (AboutLabel and TextSection comes up) will set according to that

Please see this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwokb8ge4pu5cw3/MyProfile.png?dl=0

```
class MyProfileViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var sidebarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var totalPicView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var aboutMeLabel: UITextView!

var imagesArray = [UIImageView]()
var tag: Int?


var check = false
var myUserInfo: UsersInformation!
var age: Int?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    if revealViewController() != nil
    {
        //            revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
        sidebarButton.target = revealViewController()
        sidebarButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        //revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 150
        //rightReveal.target = revealViewController()
        //rightReveal.action = "rightRevealToggle:"

        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }


    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_UID) != nil
    {

        let uid = DataService.ds.currentUserID

        DataService.ds.currentUserRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]
            {

                if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject>
                {
                    print("ProfileData")
                    self.myUserInfo = UsersInformation(id:uid, userInfo: userDictionary)

                }


            }

                /*SavingDataFUnction*/
                self.setProfileData()

        })


    }






}


func setProfileData()
{
     age = giveMeAge()

    let width = view.frame.width
    let height = view.frame.height

    print("w:\(width) ; h \(height)")


    /*Basic Information*/
    self.nameLabel.text = myUserInfo.uName
    self.ageLabel.text =    "Age: " + String(age!)
    self.aboutMeLabel.text = myUserInfo.about

    if myUserInfo.imageUrl[0] == noImageUrl
    {
        profilePic.image = UIImage(named: "Profile")

        /*Hide totalPicView and Adjust aboutLabel and TextView*/
        //totalPicView.viewWithTag(101)?.hidden = true
        //totalPicView.frame.size.height = 0


    }
    else if myUserInfo.imageUrl.count >= 1
    {





        /*FirstPic is Profile Pic*/

        let profile = myUserInfo.imageUrl[0]
        profilePic.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: profile))

       for i in 0 ... 3
        {
            let url = self.myUserInfo.imageUrl[i]
            let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(89.5 * CGFloat(i), 0, 89.5, totalPicView.frame.height))



            imgOne.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url))
            imgOne.tag = 11 + i

            imagesArray.append(imgOne)




            self.totalPicView.addSubview(imgOne)
        }

        for image: UIImageView in imagesArray
        {
            image.userInteractionEnabled = true
            image.clipsToBounds = true
            let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.setImage))
            image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        }

    }



}

func setImage(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print(gesture.view?.tag)
    tag = gesture.view?.tag

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showImages", sender: self)

    //presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}




func setMyUI(imageView: UIImageView)
{
    aboutMeLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    aboutMeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    aboutMeLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1

}



func giveMeAge() -> Int
{
    let dob = myUserInfo.dob
    let todaysDate = NSDate() //dateFromString("2015-02-04 23:29:28", format:  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    let dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"


    let currentDate = dateFormater.dateFromString(dateFormater.stringFromDate(todaysDate))

    let myDob = dateFormater.dateFromString(dob)



    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let age = calendar.components(.Year, fromDate: myDob! , toDate: currentDate!, options: [])

    return age.year
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "showImages"
    {
        let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileImages
        dest.arrarayOfImages = imagesArray
        dest.tag = tag

        dest.uname = myUserInfo.uName
        dest.myage = age
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research? How is it implemented currently? Where is your code?

Comment: I have tried to assign constraint of aboutLabel with uiview and also profilepic imageview but it didn't work for me.

Its a simple UIViewController class and I use the UIview to set the  4 images.

Comment: "didn't work for me" - is not a description of a problem. Post the code you have, show us what it did do and how this does not match what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I understand correctly you want to remove the UIView section with the 4 UIImageViews if the user has just one/no picture/s. Why not try with an if statement in your viewDidLoad (Swift 3 syntax):

```
if(yourImageViewArray.count <= 1){
  yourUIViewForImages.isHidden = true
}
```

Once your UIView `yourUIViewForImages` is hidden, your stack should adjust accordingly. Unless you have hardcoded CGRect values (x,y) for your About sections. It would really help to post your code as already mentioned in your comments section.

Comment: @SaadUllah Thanks for the code. What exactly isn't working? At a first glance I would simplify the if-statement for your array. I don't understand what `if myUserInfo.imageUrl[0] == noImageUrl` does - what is noImageUrl? And why is it followed up by an if else with the array.count? In any case just hide the UIView as I already mentioned in my answer